# $\ln x=o(x^{-\frac{1}{x}})$ (small $o$) in a neighbourhood of 0.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to solve the next problem: Prove that $\ln x=o(x^{-\frac{1}{x}})$
(small $o$) in a neighbourhood of 0.

I proved that for $\alpha>0$ we have that $\ln x=o(x^{-\alpha})$,
using the L'Hopital's rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{x^{-\alpha}}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\alpha x^{-\alpha-1}}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{1}{-\alpha x^{-\alpha}}=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x^{\alpha}=0.
$$

And with this, it follows that $\ln x=o(x^{-\alpha})$ in a neighbourhood
of 0.

I think that proving that $x^{-\alpha}=o(x^{-\frac{1}{x}})$ in a
neighbourhood of 0 then I can conclude that $\ln x=o(x^{-\frac{1}{x}})$,
since $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{x^{-\frac{1}{x}}}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{x^{-\alpha}}\cdot\frac{x^{-\alpha}}{x^{-\frac{1}{x}}}$.
But I couldn't prove that $x^{-\alpha}=o(x^{-\frac{1}{x}}).$ Could
you help me with some idea or tell me if my attempt to prove that
$\ln x=o(x^{-\frac{1}{x}})$ is incorrect?